# IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Test] and [com.srk.pkg.MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

Starting Tomcat v8.0 server at localhost encountered a problem.

apache fails to start when web app's project web.xml contains servlet info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>WebApp-01</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[image]

when servlet info is removed from web.xml, it s all right, app gets deployed, browser opens...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>WebApp-01</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

server log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Test] and [com.srk.pkg.MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2325)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2007)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1901)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Do you have annotation `@WebServlet` in `com.srk.pkg.MyServlet` class?

Comment: yes,
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {......
it works by removing that. i didnt know that annotation. thanks anyway

Comment: cool, this annotation makes servlet specification unnecessary in web.xml.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't have the same servlet mapping defined twice: in annotation and in web.xml.

When you add `@WebServlet` annotation for servlet class you dont't have to put it again in web.xml. Servlets with that annotations get started automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Sometime this problem can also be solved by just deleting server and adding server back. When you delete the server do not forget that you also have to delete the "runtime environments" of the server.

Hope this helps :)